# MongoDB is connecting but does not update

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, backend

I have not used MongoDB with NodeJS for a while so I am a bit rusty. I have written the code below and it is connecting properly but for some reason, the values are not updating. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

```js
   MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
       console.log("Connected successfully to Mongodb: Log Request (token and sender)");
       var query = {sender:senderThatAsked};
       db.collection("requestFrom").updateOne(
           query,
           {$set:{date: new Date(Date.now()).toISOString()}},
           {$setOnInsert: {
               token:tokenUsed,
               date: new Date(Date.now()).toISOString(),
               count: 0,
               sender:senderThatAsked }},
           {upsert: true}, function(err,res){
               if (err) throw err;
               console.log('The request has been logged! Now Finding...');
               db.close();
           });
       });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to use 'exec' like this : `update({}).exec((err, res) => {});`

Comment: what does .exec actually do? does it the next statement right away? Also I am not using mongoose, isn't exec only a part of mongoose?

Comment: It's the same as callback you'r passing to update.

Comment: But I think exec is only a part of mongoose right? It's telling me "....exec is not a function"

Comment: Oh right sorry ! Did not saw you where not using mongoose my bad.

Comment: The first step, *way* before posting here, should be to check the command in question's docs: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/reference/ecmascriptnext/crud/#updating-documents Under `//upsert`, `{upsert: true}` is clearly the 3rd parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
   console.log("Connected successfully to Mongodb: Log Request (token and sender)");
   var query = {sender:senderThatAsked};
   db.collection("requestFrom").updateOne(
       query,
       {
            $set:{date: new Date(Date.now()).toISOString()},
            $setOnInsert: {
                token:tokenUsed,
                count: 0,
                sender:senderThatAsked 
            }
        },
       {upsert: true}, function(err,res){
           if (err) throw err;
           console.log('The request has been logged! Now Finding...');
           db.close();
       });
   });
```

put $set and $setOnInsert in one object please

Comment: so now that they are one object, it's saying 'Cannot update 'date' and 'date' at the same time'

Comment: yes remove the date from $setOnInsert edited the answer

Comment: Just remove the `date` from `$setOnInsert` (it's for default values; if you set a parameter in `$set`, there's no need to do it again in `$setOnInsert`)

Comment: that worked! thanks! now if I anted to do a find right after this update, would the best place to do it be in the call back function?

Comment: yes it should be in call back if it has the dependency on update.